# Google map Image not loading

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, content-type

Hey guys when I load my web page the google map starts to load  but then it doesn't fully load. This is what the console prints out:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=src:apiv3".
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_ads&cad=src:apiv3,ads:0".
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_marker&cad=src:apiv3,m:2,d:0,s:0".
```

I know it has to do with the content-type but im not sure how to set it up. Im placing these two meta tags in my header but no luck.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset=utf-8">`

I am also trying another way by putting this at the top of my file:

`<?php
  // header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8');
?>`

but that doesn't help either.

I am using PHP and MYSQL. Can someone lead me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: The MIME type errors are not relevant. Every map does that, they come from Google and there is nothing you can do to change that behaviour. Your headers need to be relevant to whatever *you* are serving. Any chance of a link?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Unfortunately I dont have a link. Im developing locally at he moment. I also figured out my error. I was doing this: new google.maps.LatLng(-103.6975488, 36.8813329); However the correct way to write this would be like this: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8813329,-103.6975488);

Comment: Fine :-). Please write an answer (so it's flagged as answered) or remove the question (because none of it is relevant!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured out why my map was not loading fully. I was using this to obtain a location:

`new google.maps.LatLng(-103.6975488, 36.8813329);`

however I needed to do this:

`new google.maps.LatLng(36.8813329, -103.6975488);`

Thanks to Andrew for pointing out that MIME type errors were not revelant.

Comment: Arg, and Google Maps still doesnot show any error, just a blank map, very hard to debug.